How do I get a refund from a tax advisor who is ignoring me?
In February of 2022 I signed a "General Engagement Letter for Individual Tax Return Preparation" with a tax advisor based in Massachusetts because I thought I needed help filing my past due MA 2018 income tax forms. I paid a $200 dollar deposit, then we lost contact and I ended up filing the income tax forms myself at a later date.
I have read through the agreement and it is clear that what I paid was a deposit, and as I never supplied the advisor with any of my tax or income information, no services were ever rendered.
Since then, I emailed the tax advisor asking for the $200 deposit back in September of 2023. The credit card I had paid with earlier was stolen and replaced in the meantime, so refunding back to the original payment method was not possible. The tax advisor asked me to upload a scan of my driver's license to confirm my identity before he could mail me a check for the amount.
The tax advisor closed the message with:

"I’m sorry that you did not avail yourself of the services for which you selected and contracted".

After I uploaded my ID and emailed to confirm that the check is being mailed, I received the following reply:

"When I confirm the information, I’ll put it on my To Do list. I don’t
have an ETA for you. With the prevalence of identity theft, I’m trying
to be careful and comply with requirement of my insurance carrier."

Since September of 2023 there has been no check and no further communication between us, until I emailed them again last month, July 2023. No response. I have tried calling their office as well but I've only gotten a voicemail so far. There seems to be a way to schedule a call on their website, which I may try. But I am worried that I will get the cold shoulder again, or that they will remember who I am and try to dodge communication.
So my question is, what options do I have to compel my tax advisor to repay a deposit for services never rendered? Thank you in advance. I understand that any thoughts you contribute are not legal or financial advice. I am merely seeking to understand the situation more clearly.

Deposits are often non-refundable. Does the agreement say anything about that?

Can you explain/clarify "then we lost contact" in the first paragraph? Who dropped the ball, you or the other party?

Does this tax advisor have a place of business that you could visit and provide proof of identity and leave with a check in hand?

Update: after some persistence and discomfort on my end, I was able to convince the tax advisor to remit $175 of the deposit to me. Somehow the refund even landed in the account for the replacement of the stolen credit card. Thank you all for your help and advice!


So my question is, what options do I have to compel my tax advisor to repay a deposit for services never rendered?

Small claims court.  You'll have to do a bit of research how things work in your state.  In some states winning is only the first hurdle, collecting is sometimes improbable.  In that case you eat the $200.
It looks like you are both likely to win, and likely to collect in MA.  I would ask for any fees for filling as part of your settlement.  In your case the fee is $40.
Hopefully you can resolve this in mediation.

See this site for more details


An interesting temporizing measure is to leave a message asking for a good address to give to a process server.  To anyone that understands such things, this is a clear message that there will never be a less expensive time to make an issue go away-- whether the case is won or lost.

You sent the tax advisor money from one (now cancelled and non-existent) source, and are asking for a refund to a new one, without ever meeting them or having them do any work for you. I can see how they'd be cautious, since it follows the classic patterns of money laundering schemes.
The best action would be either a small-claims court, or asking the person how they'd want your identity to be proven to them. Driver license image sent over the email may not cut it, as those are easily forged.
